# Python collections Counter with large data

Tags: python, collections, counter

I have two text files both consisting of approximately 700,000 lines.

Second file consists of responses to statements in the first file for corresponding line.

I need to calculate Fisher's Exact Score for each word pair that appears on matching lines.

For example, if nth lines in the files are

```
how are you
```

and

```
fine thanx
```

then I need to calculate Fisher's score for (how,fine), (how,thanx), (are,fine), (are,thanx), (you,fine), (you,thanx).

In order to calculate Fisher's Exact Score, I used collections module's Counter to count the number of appearances of each word, and their co-appearances throughout the two files, as in

```
with open("finalsrc.txt") as f1, open("finaltgt.txt") as f2:
    for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
        words1 = list(set(list(find_words(line1))))
        words2 = list(set(list(find_words(line2))))
        counts1.update(words1)
        counts2.update(words2)
        counts_pair.update(list(set(list(itertools.product(words1, words2)))))
```

then I calculate the Fisher's exact score for each pair using scipy module by

```
from scipy import stats
def calculateFisher(s, t):
    sa = counts1[s]
    ta = counts2[t]
    st = counts_pair[s, t]
    snt = sa - st
    nst = ta - st
    nsnt = n - sa - ta + st
    oddsratio, pvalue = stats.fisher_exact([[st, snt], [nst, nsnt]])
    return pvalue
```

This works fast and fine for small text files,
but since my files contain 700,000 lines each, I think the Counter gets too large to retrieve the values quickly, and this becomes very very slow.

(Assuming 10 words per each sentence, the counts_pair would have (10^2)*700,000=70,000,000 entries.)

It would take tens of days to finish the computation for all word pairs in the files.

What would be the smart workaround for this?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: With 10 words per sentence, you have 10*10 = 100 word pairs per sentence pair.  Across 700,000 sentence pairs, that makes 70 million word pairs, not 700000**2 = 490 billion.  Or do I misunderstand?  If not, I just saved you a whale of a lot of work ;-)

Comment: Btw I think `list(set(list(...` can be simplified to `list(set(...`

Comment: @TimPeters thanx that was very stupid of mine. But still the problem remains...

Comment: Actually, `list(set(list(` can be removed entirely - `Counter.update()` works fine with the tuples generated by `itertools.product()`.

Comment: What does `find_words()` return?

Comment: "I think the Counter" - there's not much point "thinking" when you can know. Run the profiler, `cProfile`. Check how much time is spent in `Counter.__getitem__` (you want `cumtime` rather than `tottime`, if they're different). Check whether the proportion of time increases as the number of rows increases. If so, the Counter is getting slow. If not then it isn't.

Comment: [Pypy](http://pypy.org/) might help a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly are you calling the `calculateFisher` function? Your `counts_pair` will *not* have 70 million entries: a lot of word pairs will be seen more than once, so seventy million is the sum of their counts, not the number of keys. You should be only calculating the exact test for pairs that do co-occur, and the best place to find those is in `counts_pair`. But that means that you can just iterate over it;  and if you do, you never have to look *anything* up in `counts_pair`:

```
for (s, t), count in counts_pair.iteritems():
    sa = counts1[s]
    ta = counts2[t]
    st = count
    # Continue with Fisher's exact calculation
```

I've factored out the `calculate_fisher` function for clarity; I hope you get the idea. So if dictionary look-ups were what's slowing you down, this will save you a whole lot of them. If not, ... do some profiling and let us know what's really going on.

But note that simply looking up keys in a huge dictionary shouldn't slow things down *too* much. However, "retrieving values quickly" will be difficult if your program must to swap most of its data to disk. Do you have enough memory in your computer to hold the three counters simultaneously? Does the first loop complete in a reasonable amount of time? So find the bottleneck and you'll know more about what needs fixing.

**Edit:** From your comment it sounds like you are calculating Fisher's exact score over and over during a subsequent step of text processing. Why do that? Break up your program in two steps: First, calculate all word pair scores as I describe. Write each pair and score out into a file as you calculate it.  When that's done, use a separate script to read them back in (now the memory contains nothing else but this one large dictionary of pairs & Fisher's exact scores), and rewrite away. You should do that anyway: If it takes you ten days just to get the scores (and you **still* haven't given us any details on what's slow, and why), get started and in ten days you'll have them forever, to use whenever you wish.

I did a quick experiment, and a python process with a list of a million `((word, word), count)` tuples takes just 300MB (on OS X, but the data structures should be about the same size on Windows). If you have 10 million distinct word pairs, you can expect it to take about 2.5 GB of RAM. I doubt you'll have even this many word pairs (but check!). So if you've got 4GB of RAM and you're not doing anything wrong that you haven't told us about, you should be all right. Otherwise, YMMV.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. I need to clarify that I need to calculate the score of word pairs on a need base in certain order(although eventually that'll be all pairs in counts_pair). I basically need to rewrite the lines from input files into some other form according to the score. So the counts need to be retrieved according to that order..

Comment: This sounds like you're calculating the score over and over for the same word pair. Do it in two steps, as described in the edited answer. (And **find out** where your program is spending its time, and whether it's due to swapping.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm currently trying your approach, and this is really embarrassing to ask, but the for loop code you provided gives me ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack... This is perhaps an idiotically simple question, but I cannot figure out what the problem is..

Comment: Oops, I accidentally flattened the tuple-unpacking. Please try the new loop from above. The problem is that (s,t) is the counter's key, and it comes out in a tuple when you iterate.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. The count of entries in counts_pair apparently turns out to be 73,375,087, which should be about 18GB according to you.. I first tried storing them in python dictionary but obviously ran out of memory, and then tried sqlite, but its insert gets exponentially slow as the size grows.. If I were to write to a file and retrieve the value when needed, what would be the most efficient way? I'm realizing how algorithmically ignorant I am. :(

Comment: Try setting up a real database (mysql). But that's a lot more word pairs than expected: If your sentences have around 10 words each, you can only end up with this many pairs if there are NO repeated word pairs-- how is this possible? Somehow, your code does not match the description you've given here.

Comment: Anyway, if you're ending up with this many pairs I think you should take another step back and think about what you're trying to accomplish with this calculation. I'd bet money there is a simpler way.

Comment: thank you. "10 words each" was said just to illustrate what I mean by 'word pairs'. Each line could be anywhere from 1 to tens of words. Anyway, I think your approach does reduce the time significantly, so I give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that your bottleneck is in how you manipulate the data structures other than the counters.

`words1 = list(set(list(find_words(line1))))` creates a list from a set from a list from the result of `find_words`. Each of these operations requires allocating memory to hold all of your objects, and copying. Worse still, if the type returned by `find_words` does not include a `__len__` method, the resulting list will have to grow and be recopied as it iterates.

I'm assuming that all you need is an iterable of unique words in order to update your counters, for which `set` will be perfectly sufficient.

```
for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
    words1 = set(find_words(line1)) # words1 now has list of unique words from line1
    words2 = set(find_words(line2)) # words2 now has list of unique words from line2
    counts1.update(words1)          # counts1 increments words from line1 (once per word)
    counts2.update(words2)          # counts2 increments words from line2 (once per word)
    counts_pair.update(itertools.product(words1, words2)
```

Note that you don't need to change the output of `itertools.product` that is passed to  `counts_pair` as there are no repeated elements in `words1` or `words2`, so the Cartesian product will not have any repeated elements.

Comment: thanx for the reply but this doesn't seem to yield a significant boost in speed... Could there be any other improvement?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to generate the cross-products lazily - a `Counter` with 70 million elements will take a lot of RAM and suffer from cache misses on virtually every access.

So how about instead save a dict mapping a "file 1" word to a list of sets of corresponding "file 2" words?

Initial:

```
word_to_sets = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Replace:

```
   counts_pair.update(list(set(list(itertools.product(words1, words2)))))
```

with:

```
   for w1 in words1:
       word_to_sets[w1].append(words2)
```

Then in your Fisher function, replace this:

```
st = counts_pair[s, t]
```

with:

```
    st = sum(t in w2set for w2set in word_to_sets.get(s, []))
```

That's as lazy as I can get - the cross-products are never computed at all ;-)

**EDIT** Or map a "list 1" word to its own `Counter`:

Initial:

```
word_to_counter = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

Replace:

```
   counts_pair.update(list(set(list(itertools.product(words1, words2)))))
```

with:

```
   for w1 in words1:
       word_to_counter[w1].update(words2)
```

In Fisher function:

```
    st = word_to_counter[s][t]
```

Comment: This seems a little bit faster, but not very noticeably... Could the problem be on scipy's side?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc, well, I can't profile it from here ;-)  See the edit for a related approach that does less work on the Python side.

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc, the Fisher exact statistic is cheap enough to compute, so doubt (but don't *know*) `scipy` is at fault.  You have a lot of data!  It's going to take a while no matter what you do.